# import Excel columns to listboxes

Tags: c#

I need to import 3 columns from Excel to 3 different listboxes

- Col a to listbox 1
- Col b to listbox 2
- Col c to listbox 3

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258141/how-to-import-data-from-one-column-of-excel-to-listbox-using-c-sharp

Comment: How can i select that colume a will incert to listbox 1 ?? I try this link its not help

Answer (score 1):

Always good to show your effort what you try.I think you want some thing like this.

```
string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", YourPath);
    string query = String.Format(SELECT [columnName1],[columnName2],[columnName3] from [{0}$]", "YourSheetNo");
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    DataTable YourTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
    listbox1.DataSource =YourTable.Columns["ColumnName1"];
```